# How to get a collection of elements with playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, playwright

How to get all images on the page with playwright?
I'm able to get only one (`ElementHandle`) with following code, but not a collection.

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

class Parser {
  async parse(url) {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor("img");
    // TODO: get somehow collection of elements
    return await page.$("img");
  }
}

module.exports = Parser;
```

Somewhere in another module far far away:

```
const Parser = require("./path/to/dir/Parser.js");
const parser = new Parser();

parser
    .parse(body.url)
    .then(elemHandle => {
      // here I get only one ElementHandle object, but suppose to get an array or collection
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
```

Node v.12.16.1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have already found the answer. Need to use `page.$$(selector)` instead of `page.$(selector)` to grab like `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`.

Comment: @EugZ- how about the length?

Comment: for length use .length .For e.g:
 const counts = await page.$$(selector);
expect(counts.length).toBe(3)

Answer (score 9):

You want to use the new method `locator.all()`, added in **[v1.29](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/releases/tag/v1.29.0)**, to iterate over all matching elements:

```js
// returns all images on the page & stores them in an array
const images = await page.getByRole('img').all();
```

The usage of `await page.$$(selector);` is discouraged. Use locator-based `page.locator()` instead. You can read about the method [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer , most of others are outdated.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can use `await page.$$(selector)`.
Here is a [link to the page.$$ official documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page/#pageselector-1)

You can also use the following code.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector) , selector);
```

Here is a [link to the page.evaluate official documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageevaluatepagefunction-arg)

Answer (score 6):

For counting, when trying to avoid the use of `await page.$$(selector);`, another alternative is to directly use LocatorAssertion:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveCount(n);
```

[Link to official documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count)

Comment: the official docs helped

Answer (score 5):

- for playwright use: await page.$$(selector);

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to work with a list of elements you can read from the documentation. And I like it much more
https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#lists

So you just select using the page.locator and after that, you can interact with each element using for loop or selected the needed element using .nth()

Answer (score 2):

Locator seems to be the current way forward. `page.$$(img)` is discouraged.

Instead use:

```
const imageList = await page.locator('img);
```

For count:

```
const imageList = await page.locator('img');
console.log('images: ', await imageList.count());
```

More information on https://playwright.dev/docs/locators

However, to answer the question of getting all images depending on how you to store them but Ill use an array.

```
const tmpArray = [];
const imageList = await page.locator('img');
for (let i = 0; i < await imageList.count(); i++) {
    const element = await imageList.nth(i).getAttribute('src');
    tmpArray.push(element)
}
```

You can also store imageList.count() in a variable and use that instead in your for loop

Comment: This is so ugly, just to iterate over a list of elements you cant use the list directly but instead have to get the count and call the nth child by the index...

Comment: @BennyAlex not sure what you're trying to get at but the OP wants to get all the images on a page. How OP intends to use the collection isnt specified but my answer provides the OP with a solution to store the source of all images in an array. If he or she wants to pop, at or find for later use then this is a viable solution