# Getting a list of list elements using Playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, playwright

I am trying to write an application where it will go to amazon and get a list of books on the page. I am using Playwright as the tool. I can get to the right section but I can't get the list of books. Looking online the examples seem to use `page.$$(selector)` but when I try that, I get an empty array back. Found this information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453673/how-to-get-a-collection-of-elements-with-playwright) and [here](https://applitools.medium.com/playing-with-playwright-86257fd0a030). Reading the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageselector-1) on `$$`, this seems like the right call as all the list elements have the same class name. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any advice on this?

Here is my code so far;

```
const AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-eBooks/zgbs/digital-text/154606011/ref=zg_bs_nav_kstore_1_kstore/';
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    try {
        const amazonPage = await browser.newPage();
        await amazonPage.goto(AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL);

        await amazonPage.waitForSelector('"Best Sellers in"');
        await amazonPage.click('"Self-Help"');
        await amazonPage.click('"Creativity"')

        const books = await amazonPage.$$('li[class="zg-item-immersion"]');
        console.log(books);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

For the selector I have tried it numerous ways as well;

- `li[class="zg-item-immersion"]` - This actually worked checking on the dev console
- `'zg-item-immersion'`
- `#zg-item-immersion`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the only problem is that Plawright is too fast and you don't wait for those elements `li[class="zg-item-immersion"]`.

I debugged the script and the selector is fine, so with this line, it returns 50 element handles:

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

const AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-eBooks/zgbs/digital-text/154606011/ref=zg_bs_nav_kstore_1_kstore/';
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false});
    try {
        const amazonPage = await browser.newPage();
        await amazonPage.goto(AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL);

        await amazonPage.waitForSelector('"Best Sellers in"');
        await amazonPage.click('"Self-Help"');

        await Promise.all([
            amazonPage.waitForNavigation(),
            amazonPage.click('"Creativity"')
        ]);
        
        const books = await amazonPage.$$('li[class="zg-item-immersion"]');
        console.log(books);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

you can perhaps do what you did a few lines above and for a selector:

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

const AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-eBooks/zgbs/digital-text/154606011/ref=zg_bs_nav_kstore_1_kstore/';
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false});
    try {
        const amazonPage = await browser.newPage();
        await amazonPage.goto(AMAZON_KINDLE_EBOOK_STORE_URL);

        await amazonPage.waitForSelector('"Best Sellers in"');
        await amazonPage.click('"Self-Help"');
        await amazonPage.click('"Creativity"')

        await amazonPage.waitForSelector('li[class="zg-item-immersion"]');
        const books = await amazonPage.$$('li[class="zg-item-immersion"]');
        console.log(books);
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

It does work like this as well.

Comment: Thanks @pavelsaman, that worked a treat for me. So anytime the pages changes/updates always use the `waitForSelector` before doing any actions